# Matching field + "Ctiy"

Tags: sql

How would you solve this problem:

You have a table with country names and capitals like this:

tk, name, capital

How would you SELECT name where countries equals capital + "City". So you would get results like Mexico City and Panama City etc?

This question come from the following problem:
"The capital of Mexico is Mexico City. Show all the countries where the capital has the country together with the word "City".

Find the country where the capital is the country plus "City"."

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I'd concatenate the country column and the string literal, and equals compare with the city column.

Comment: Not strictly in the spirit of the question however given there are only 5 countries in the world this applies to the most performant query would be `select Name from Countries where Name in ('Guatemala','Kuwait','Mexico','Panama','Vatican City');`

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the country's name to ' City'  then compare it to its capital in the `where` clause:

```
select name
from countries
where capital = name || ' City';
```

Comment: Note that concat() is a product specific function. ANSI SQL has the `||` concatenation operator.

Comment: @jarlh you're right, it doesn't exist at least in sqlite. Thank you!

Comment: Without knowing the DBMS .. This answer is a "shot in the dark"